# Nginx: unknown directive "uwsgi_param" in /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params:1

Tags: server, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Using [this deployment tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/ssuser163469/deploying-flask-with-nginx-uwsgi), I'm trying to get an Ubuntu 12.04 server up and running with Flask, uWSGI and Nginx. I now have trouble getting Nginx to run. When I try to (re)start nginx it simply says `...fail!`, and when I run a test (using `sudo nginx -t`), it says:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "uwsgi_param" in /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I didn't change anything in that file, so its contents are the default ones:

```
uwsgi_param     QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
uwsgi_param     REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
uwsgi_param     CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
uwsgi_param     CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

uwsgi_param     REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
uwsgi_param     PATH_INFO               $document_uri;
uwsgi_param     DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME            $scheme;

uwsgi_param     REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param     REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_NAME             $server_name;
```

My server definition in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www` looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name myapp;

    root /var/www/myapp;
    try_files $uri @uwsgi;
    location @uwsgi {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Why doesn't this run? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix for me was as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-full
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of nginx installed doesn't support UWSGI. It's fairly easy to find one that does:

```
% apt-cache search nginx uwsgi
nginx-core - nginx web/proxy server (core version)
nginx-extras - nginx web/proxy server (extended version)
nginx-full - nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

That means all of those packages contain uwsgi in their package descriptions, which is usually in the positive sense. You can verify that simply by looking at the description, e.g. `apt-cache show packagename`.